# Erro ao tentar instalar MySQL Client

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Estou tentando instalar o mysqlclient no Windows usando o pip, para poder usa-lo no Flask, mas quando eu tento usar o pip install no CMD (com os arquivos baixados no site https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) aparece a mensagem:

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei aqui na minha máquina e tive o mesmo problema. No fim das contas, o problema era bem simples, causado apenas por uma diferença na codificação do caractere `-` (hífen) no comando que você digitou.

Copie e cole exatamente esse comando abaixo no CMD, na mesma pasta onde você baixou o arquivo **mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl**, que vai funcionar:

`pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl`

**OBS** - Pode passar a impressão de que esse comando é idêntico ao que você postou, mas não é. Aqui os hífens já estão corrigidos com a codificação correta.

Comment: Eu tenho que colocar o arquivo baixado em uma pasta específica? Porque eu continuo com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Olá, desculpe a demora em responder, só vi agora. Sim, você precisa rodar o comando no CMD a partir da mesma pasta onde você baixou o arquivo. O jeito mais fácil pra fazer isso é abrir o Windows Explorer (gerenciador de arquivos), navegar para a pasta onde você baixou o arquivo `mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl`, mantenha a tecla `SHIFT` pressionada, clique com o botão direito do mouse e escolha a opção `Abrir a janela de comando aqui`. Depois, é só rodar o comando da minha resposta.

Comment: Era esse o problema, muito obrigado pela ajuda!